# micro-ROS command line explanation - ros2 - RTOS - micro-ROS Tutorials

Tags: stm32, esp32, rtos, ros2

`ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_firmware_ws.sh nuttx olimex-stm32-e407`
Can someone please explain me this command line!

*where will I get expalantions about the command lines? Documentation?*
*From above command line, I want to use esp32 or stm32f4 Board instead of olimex-stm32-e407, how to do that in working way?*

**Explanation**
I am following tutorial for micro-ROS [enter link description here](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/nuttx/). I want to use STM32F4 and ESP32 Board instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows the basic `ros2 run` format. To break it down `ros2 run` is simply used to run(*not launch*) an executable under the ros2 environment. It also takes the format of `ros2 run <package> <executable>`, so this means `micro_ros_setup` is the ros2 package it's searching and `create_firmware_ws.sh` is the executable. The next two arguments, `nuttx olimex-stm32-e407`, are just passed onto the bash script to be used internally. I'm not familiar with who released this ros2 package, however, using a shell script with `ros2 run` is not something that should be done and is bad design.